# Same appium code doesnot work for same app

Tags: java, ruby, appium

I am Automating the app with Appium. i had a hybrid app that is made upon react-native the whole code is works when there is no splash screen. If there is splash screen the same code doesn't work. I am getting `Element not found` error. I had tried in both language `java` and `ruby`. I had tried by hiding splash screen it works but it is quite difficult in every build to replace the splash screen on for automation. Splash screen is made on java code.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you please share the error log with us? One question, while there is no splash screen, is the application opening ?

Comment: @AlImran had posted image above  after your comment.

Comment: Can you post the Appium server logs? The IOException seems to indicate that the session ends up in a bad state rather than just not finding the Element.

Comment: @Domestus i had posted in question Appium server log above after your request .

Comment: Thanks. Can't see any mention of the exception on the Appium server log unfortunately.. Does automationName: "UiAutomator2" help?

Comment: @Domestus I think exception is because expire of time. File doesn't consist  UiAutomator2.

Answer (score 0):

try using implict or explict wait when the app starts

```
//implict wait
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

//or use explict wait
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("someid")));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java's `Thread.sleep()` method to make your Appium code wait until specific element is displayed.

Example:

```
public void sampleTest() throws InterruptedException {
    Thread.sleep(5000L);

    // Your sample Appium codes
}
```

This will always allow Appium server to wait for the amount of time you pass in the `Thread.sleep()` method, until the desired element is available to locate